# MEF: What if I have multiple exports but need only one import?

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm trying to wrap my mind around MEF.
There is one thing I don't understand.

Assume that I have an interface, named ISomething, which is a contract, and I have more than one assemblies in a folder that contains my application, and I have no idea how many ISomething implementations are in them, or which one contains one.

If I create a host application in which I use MEF, and would like to get an ISomething, but only one, how does MEF decide which implementation it will give me?

Or, similarly to a common IoC container, how do I tell it which implementation should it use?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsplaisted/archive/2009/08/10/import-cardinality-and-picking-which-export-to-use.aspx) for a discussion of this issue and some of the options you have.  Also, Glenn Block has a blog post describing how to [customize the container behavior with defaults](http://blogs.msdn.com/gblock/archive/2009/05/14/customizing-container-behavior-part-2-of-n-defaults.aspx).

Comment: Glenn's post about ExportProviders just gave me a good idea. Perhaps I should make an ExportProvider that accepts some sort of configuration in which the default export can be specified.

Comment: That is perfectly resonable, and it was one of the scenarios we considered.

Answer (score 11):

In the case of MEF, if you have many Exports that will satisfy an Import, you have two options:

1. Change your Import around to use `[ImportMany]`.  Decide, at runtime, which of the Imports to use for your contract, potentially just picking the first, or one at random.
2. Use `[ImportMany]` in conjunction with [Metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide) in order to decide which Import to use.

Comment: This is a good idea, however, I would prefer to do something like in Windsor, to specify a concrete implementation from configuration, and tell MEF to use that.

Comment: @Venemo: You should be able to do that, using the metadata at runtime.