# Overriding MEF Composition

Tags: .net, mef

How can I override MEF composition so that if an importing constructor ask for a single dependency and there is multiple implementation of this required dependency it would take the implementation (export) with the highest priority (metadata)?

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
[ExportMetadata("Priority", 1)]
public class Service1 : IService
{
}

[Export(typeof(IService))]
[ExportMetadata("Priority", 2)]
public class Service2 : IService
{
}

public interface IService
{
}

public class ServiceWithDependencies
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ServiceWithDependencies(IService service)
    {

    }
}
```

ServiceWithDependencies would normally not be satisfied since there is more than one implementation of IService. But I would like to modify MEF (override/intercept something) so that it would use the priority metadata and inject the implementation with the highest priority into the ServiceWithDependencies constructor.

**Edit 1**

I don't want MEF to dictate the way I do things. I want it to be invisible as much as possible. Furthermore, this is for a framework and I don't have control on how people will require dependencies. I need to support basic constructor injection. I know about [ImportMany], but this question is precisely about constructor injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting priority metadata on your parts, you can also put them in different catalogs and then [prioritize the catalogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520170/how-to-prioritize-different-catalogs/9530447).

In our applications, we make use of this to give highest priority to parts in a `plugins` folder, then the parts in the application exe, and finally all the other libraries.

**edit**: Here's a full sample.

First, the types:

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class Service1 : IService { }

[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class Service2 : IService { }

public interface IService { }

[Export]
public class ServiceWithDependency
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ServiceWithDependency(IService service)
    {
    }
}

[Export]
public class ServiceWithMultipleDependencies
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ServiceWithMultipleDependencies(
        [ImportMany] IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is how you can set up the container:

```
var priorityCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Service1));
var priorityProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(priorityCatalog);

var mainCatalog = new TypeCatalog(
    typeof(ServiceWithDependencies),
    typeof(ServiceWithMultipleDependencies),
    typeof(Service2));
var mainProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(mainCatalog);

// priorityProvider gets priority because it is first
var container = new CompositionContainer(
    priorityProvider, mainProvider);
priorityProvider.SourceProvider = container;
mainProvider.SourceProvider = container;

// will get constructed with Service1
var foo = container.GetExportedValue<ServiceWithDependency>();

// will get constructed with both, proving that both are available
var bar = container.GetExportedValue<ServiceWithMultipleDependencies>();
```

Comment: Sorry if I am slow, but I don't understand how this could help with constructor injection.

Comment: There is no conflict with constructor injection, we use that as well.

Comment: I did not say that there was a problem, I just said that I don't understand how it works. Sorry again, but I am a newbie in the MEF world. Could you explain in the context of the example above?

Comment: I saw your answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750640/intercepting-dependencies-in-mef  Do you think the InterceptingCatalog would be of any help for my situation?

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tonight, but it seems do do the job. I guess I just have to filter the services on priority and keep only the ones with the highest priority for the priorityCatalog and add all the services to the mainCatalog?

Comment: @W3Max: That could work. In our case we simply give higher priority to the assemblies in a certain subdirectory ("plugins").

Comment: It works (constructor injection) but I now have a duplicate when I do ImportMany. I don't know if I could filter it out...

Comment: @W3Max: that's the expected result if you have the same part in both catalogs. You could make sure that you use different assemblies for each catalog, or you could use something like a [FilteredCatalog](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2010/10/mef-filtered-catalog.html).

Answer (score 1):

the easy way would be to [ImportMany] and let chosse the one with the highest Metadata. <-- Thats what we do in our projects.

More information of what you can do - you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876064/mef-what-if-i-have-multiple-exports-but-need-only-one-import).

```
public class ServiceWithDependencies
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ServiceWithDependencies([ImportManyAttribute]IEnumerable<Lazy<IService, IServiceMetadata>> services)
    {
       this._TheServiceIWant = services.Max(x=>x.Metadata.Prio).First().Instance;
    }
}
```

ps: code is handwritten, so linq would not be right - maybe

EDIT:

instead of handle the services in your class directly you can also import and factory wich has some methods like:

```
 MyPluginFac.GiveServiceWithHighestPrio();
 MyPluginFac.GiveServiceWithPrio(1);
 ...

public class ServiceWithDependencies
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ServiceWithDependencies(IServiceFac serviceFac)
    {
       this._TheServiceIWant = serviceFac.GiveServiceWithHighestPrio();
    }
}
```

Comment: With respect, this is too much ceremony. I don't want MEF to dictate the way I do things. I want it to be invisible as much as possible. Furthermore, this is for a framework and I don't have control on how people will require dependencies. I need to support basic constructor injection. I know about [ImportMany], but this question is precisely about constructor injection.

Comment: the good thing for the factory solution is, that you have one container and you can get what you want out of it.

Comment: but you are right, instead of IService you have to import IServiceFac